# How to print a list that is made up of function outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code is a fast food menu and after the user has selected an option fully it gets stored in the list Order.
I want to print the Order list once the order is complete to show what the user has ordered i.e:
Burger with cheese.

But instead it is outputing:
<**main**.Burger object at 0x0000027BB1221490>

```
     def user_input_burger():
        bur = input("What burger would you like?: 1. Beef 2. Chicken")
        while True:
            if bur.lower() == "1" or bur.lower() == "beef":
               toppings = input("What toppings would you like?: 1. Cheese 2. No Cheese")
               while toppings.lower() not in ["cheese", "no cheese", "1", "2"]:
                   print("Invalid selection")
                   toppings = input("What toppings would you like?: 1. Cheese 2. No Cheese")
               b = Burger(bur.lower(), toppings.lower())
               if toppings.lower() == "c":
                   print("Order Cancelled")
                   b = 1
          elif bur.lower() == "c":
              print("Order Cancelled")
              b = 1
      return b

   def take_order():
         Order = []
         print("Welcome to Burger Shop!")
         user = input("Enter your name: ")
         print("Hello" + " " + user + ". " + "Enter c to cancel order at any time.")
         go = 0

   burgers = input("Would you like a burger? (Y/N): ")
   while burgers.lower() != "n" and go == 0:
       if burgers.lower() not in ["y", "n", "c"]:
          print("Invalid selection")
          burgers = input("Would you like a burger? (Y/N): ")
       elif burgers.lower() == "y":
          t = user_input_burger()
          Order.append(t)
          if t==1:
              go = 1
          else:
              burgers=input("Would you like another burger? (Y/N): ")
       elif burgers.lower() == "n":
           break
       else:
           print("Order Cancelled")
           break
  for i in Order:
      print(i)

    take_order()
```

Comment: The typical code path in `user_input_burger()` looks like it returns a `Burger()` and that is added to the `Order` array and then printed.  Does `Burger()` define `__str__` and `__repl__`?

Comment: The code you have given doesn't contain the Burger class. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The output you are seeing is the output of `Burger.__str__` (which is just the inherited `object.__str__`  method). Define your own `Burger.__str__` to return whatever string you want.

Answer (score 0):

First you set

```
b = Burger(bur.lower(), toppings.lower())
```

and if toppings is "c" you set it to 1.

do get you started. There are other errors there, but this is the main one.